# Union and Intersection of families of initial segments

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm trying to show that unions and intersections of families of initial segments are initial segments.

An initial segment of a partially ordered set X is a subset of A such that, for every x$\in$X and a$\in$A we have x $\leq$ a $\in$ A -> x $\in$ A.

My Attempt:

Let $A_i$ be an initial segment of $X$ for every $i\in I$. let $a\in A$, $x\in X$  and suppose $x\le a$. It follows that a $\in$ $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ and $x\le a$$\in$ $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ so therefore, x $\in$ $A=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$. Hence, x $\in$ A and $A=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ is an initial segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A_i$ be an initial segment of $X$ for every $i\in I$.  Then you want to show that
$$A=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$$
is an initial segment of $X$.  So, let $a\in A$ and suppose $x\le a$.  Then

(1) what do you know about $a$ in relation to the segments $A_i$?

(2) what does this tell you about $x$ in relation to the segments $A_i$?

(3) what does this tell you about $x$ in relation to $A$?

(4) how does this prove the result?

Good luck!

Comment: Your outline was extremely helpful! I just edited my question and included my attempt at the proof- am I missing anything or is anything incorrect?

Comment: Just been off m.se for the weekend ;-) ...bit hard to answer the last comment as I don't know what sort of thing your instructor is after, but if it was me I would probably want to see how the *individual* segments $A_i$ come into the picture - everything you have written refers to the union of all $A_i$.  Can you say anything about $a$, and consequently $x$, in terms of each individual $A_i$?